# My code (C++) works in IDE but not hackerrank

Tags: c++, initialization, gcc-warning

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int res, k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x,y = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            x += a[j];
        }
        for(int j = n-1; j > i; j--) {
            y += a[j];
        }
        if(res > abs(x-y)) {
            res = abs(x-y);
            k = i+1;
        }
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

    }
    cout << k;
}
```

My code works fine in visual studio code but it shows this error in hackerrank

```
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Solution.cpp:22:9: warning: ‘res’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         if(res > abs(x-y)) {
         ^~
```

clearly I've defined the res variable, where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To initialize both `res` and `k` to 0, you need to do:

```
int res = 0, k = 0;
```

or

```
int res = 0;
int k = 0;
```

but not

```
int res, k = 0;
```

The error is telling you that while you have declared `res`, it's possible that you try to use it before you have set it to some value.

Answer (score 1):

it's true what hackerank says, you use `res` before you initialize it, in the `if(res > abs(x-y))` comparison.
In fact you only declare it, without initialize it before use.
If your compiler in the IDE doesn't show the error, maybe has as default some options that suppress these warning type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set or initialize res before using it in below statements.

```
if(res > abs(x-y)) {
            res = abs(x-y);
            k = i+1;
}
```